# Crystal IfNull variant on multi-part statement

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the following formula that I'm using in crystal reports:

```
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.ORDER_ID}),0,"")&"-"& 
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.INVOICE_ID}),0)&"-
"&ToText(ToNumber({PACKAGE.PACKAGE_ID}),0)
```

I need it to display just Order and Invoice if the package doesn't exist.
I've tried the following:

```
IFNULL({PACKAGE.PACKAGE_ID} then 
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.ORDER_ID}),0,"")&"-"& 
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.INVOICE_ID}),0) 
else 
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.ORDER_ID}),0,"")&"-"& 
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.INVOICE_ID}),0)&"-
"&ToText(ToNumber({PACKAGE.PACKAGE_ID}),0)
```

I receive an error: "The rest of the text is not part of the formula" and it highlights the entire statement.

I believe I'm close but can't seem to figure this out. I'm relatively new to crystal reports so any advised would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF ISNULL({PACKAGE.PACKAGE_ID}) then 
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.ORDER_ID}),0,"")&"-"& 
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.INVOICE_ID}),0)
else 
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.ORDER_ID}),0,"")&"-"& 
ToText(ToNumber({INVOICE.INVOICE_ID}),0)&"-
"&ToText(ToNumber({PACKAGE.PACKAGE_ID}),0)
```

Comment: Looks like I missed more than I thought.. Thanks this worked.

Comment: No probs.. Easy to miss those () sometimes